# How to do "component testing" in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for ideas to lead me to implement component testing for my application. Sure I use  Unit Testing to test my single methods by utilizing TestMethods in a separate project but at this point I am more interested in testing in a higher level. Say that I have a class for Caching and I wrote unit tests for each and every method. They all contain their own instance of the class. And it works fine when I run the test, it initiates an object from that class and does one thing on it. But this doesnt cover the real life scenario in which the method is called by other methods and so on. I want to be able to test the entire caching component. How  should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about integration testing. Unit testing, as you say, does a great job of testing classes and methods in isolation but itegration testing tests that several components work together as expected.

One way to do this is to pick a top (or high) level object, create it with all of its dependencies as "real" objects as well and test that the public methods all produce the expected result.

In most cases you'll probably have to substitute stubs of the lowest level classes, like DB or file access classes and instrument them for the tests, but most objects would be the real thing.

Of course, like most testing efforts, all this is achieved much easier if your classes have been designed with some sort of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and paying attention to good design patterns like [separation of concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

All of this can be done using the same unit testing tools you've been using.

Comment: This makes sense. I need my components to be very modular and independent from each other in this case. It does depend very much on the structure the way you described it. Maybe I could start by dividing into different modules and mock the communication between them ?

Comment: If you are dealing with legacy code, refactoring into testable classes and modules like this can be, um, _challenging_ (a fun challenge if you're into such things). But, yes, dividing and separating functionality and accessing it via DI is the right way to go, IMO.

Answer (score -5):

I would download the NUNIT-Framework

http://www.nunit.org/

It's free and simple

Comment: Why does N-Unit work better than the unit testing tools in Visual Studio that the original poster is already using?

Comment: how does it help me for component testing ?